# pywinauto does not send text to static elements

Tags: python, testing, automation, pywinauto

I have tried to send text to textbox on the application which does not fail but also does not enter text.

```
app = Application(backend='uia').start(r"C:\Users\user\app_creator.exe")
win = app.window(best_match='App Creator')
time.sleep(2)

win['Select an Active Window'].type_keys('u')
win['SAVE IMAGE'].click()
win.wait('ready')
win['Boo'].type_keys("Test1")
win['Foo'].type_keys("Test2")
win['Area'].type_keys('w')
win['SUBMIT'].click()
```

This Boo, Foo are child window and static as far as I know we can interact a Dynamic ones. This is the list of elements gathered with `app.AppCreator.print_control_identifiers()`

Control Identifiers for Boo, Foo is

```
Static - 'Foo'    (L885, T618, R930, B637)
   |    | ['FooStatic', 'Foo', 'Static2']
   |    | child_window(title="Foo", auto_id="lblFoo", control_type="Text")

Static - 'Boo'    (L886, T592, R920, B611)
   |    | ['BooStatic', 'Boo', 'Static3']
   |    | child_window(title="Boo", auto_id="lblBoo", control_type="Text")
```

Is there any way to send text or select Static elements?

Thank for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? Edit static elements? How do you imagine that? You even can't edit them manually, but trying to do it by script? Hey man, you shall have no luck.

The answer: it's impossible.